# ZAProxy: 400 HTTP response when attack on localhost:8080

Tags: php, security, firefox, localhost, zap

I installed ZAProxy and FireFox, ensuring that the proxy is set correctly and is the same for both tools, localhost and 8080. I have a web app named *openemr* currently running on an XAMPP Apache server, and I can access it as `http://localhost:8080/openemr` from within FireFox.

The problem is in Zap, in the "Quick Start" option: if I paste the above URL and click "Attack", it shows an error:

> Failed to attack the URL: received 400 response code

As an alternative, I also tried to access the web app from FireFox, but it does not appear in the website listing in Zap for launching attack.

Did I miss any step?

On the other hand, I was able to just copy and paste URLs (like a wiki page website) to attack. That seems to be working fine. Likewise, if I browse an active website in FireFox, it shows up in the website list of Zap for scanning.

The Zap version is 2.6. It seems unlikely that the Java version would be an issue -- I have not checked it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I formatted the error message and rephrased some sentences and the title to improve the clarity. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It will definitely be a configuration issue - I use ZAP to attack local apps all the time :)

Are you starting ZAP on another port? You'll need to do that so they dont clash. You can change it via the ZAP options or use the `-port` command line option.

Its worth requesting the URL via the Manual Request Editor - see https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQquickScanFailed for more details.

Comment: Indeed, I changed Zap port from 8080 to 8081, it started working right away! Thanks for the help.